# Minimizing curves are geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.

I want to prove the following claim:

> Let $c:[0,1]\to M$ be a smooth curve from $p$ to $q$ such that $L(c)=d(p,q)$. Then $c$ is, up to reparametrization, a geodesic.

And I can use the following:

> **Fact:** For each $p\in M$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $q,q'\in B_\delta(p)$, there exists a unique minimizing geodesic from $q$ to $q'$.

Some observations:

- $c$ not only minimizes the distance from $p$ to $q$ but in fact between any two points on the curve: If that were not the case, then we would have $L(\tilde c)<L(c|_{[s,t]})$ for some other curve $\tilde c$ from $c(s)$ to $c(t)$. From that we obtain $L(c|_{[0,s]}\cup \tilde{c}\cup c|_{[t,1]})<L(c)$, contradicting the assumption that $c$ is minimizing.
- The curve $c$ can be covered by finitely many balls of some radius $\delta>0$ as in the fact above. So for points $q$ and $q'$ within the ball there exists a minimizing geodesic connecting $q$ and $q'$. On the other hand, $c$ is a minimizing curve connecting $q$ and $q'$.

Does it necessarily follow that on the segment from $q$ to $q'$, the curve $c$ coincides with the geodesic guaranteed by the fact?

Any clarification is more than welcome.

Comment: Your **Fact** isn't quite clear about whether the minimizing geodesic is unique amongst all  *curves* or just amongst all *geodesics*. If the former, then the uniqueness means it must coincide with $c$; but if the latter then (a priori) it's possible they do not coincide and $c$ is not geodesic. Both versions of the fact are true, but you need the stronger one. As for your argument, be careful: the radius $\delta$ can depend on the point $p$. This won't be an issue, though - you can still get a finite cover by such balls using compactness (if finiteness is even required).

Comment: Good point, @AnthonyCarapetis. To be clear, the stronger version says: For $p\in M$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $q,q'\in B_\delta(p)$ there exists a unique minimizing curve from $q$ to $q'$, which is a geodesic?

Comment: By the way, why then is $c$ only a geodesic after potentially reparametrizing?

Comment: yes, that's a clear statement of the strong version. Note that reparametrizations of geodesics are not necessarily geodesics. If you distinguish parametrizations as separate curves (so that it makes sense to ask whether a curve is a geodesic) then you need to amend your fact (since reparametrizations make the uniqueness fail), so instead it's more convenient to let a single "curve" include all possible parametrizations, at which point you can say a curve is a "geodesic up to reparametrization" if it has some parametrization that is a geodesic.

Comment: Thanks, @AnthonyCarapetis, that clears a lot up for me.

Answer (score 1):

(1) (Reference : Riemannian geometry - do Carmo) Assume that $c$ is a piecewise curve from $p$ to $q$ s.t. for any curve $c'$ from $p$ to $q$ $$ l(c') \geq l(c)$$ where $l$ is length. Then $c$ is a geodesic up to reparametrization :

Proof : As you commented, we have totally normal neighhood at $c(t)$, $B_{\delta_t} c(t)=\exp_{c(t)} B_{\delta_t}(0)$ That is, any two points in the ball can be connected unique minimal geodesic. So in each ball $c$ must be a geodesic. And if $c$ has singularity, then at the point, by using totally normal neighborhood we can rule out singularity.

(2) Now define a distance function $d(p,q)=\inf_c l(c)$ So there exists a curve $c$ s.t. $$ l(c)-d(p,q) <\epsilon $$

By $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$, and arzela-ascoli theorem we have the existence of $c$ s.t. $l(c)=d(p,q)$ By previous $c$ is a geodesic.